# Conditionally insert and return rowid or 0?

Tags: sql, sqlite, common-table-expression, rowid, sql-returning

I know how to do this using a transaction but I was wondering if I can do this in a single line. My actual query is more complex but the part I can't figure out is how to get the rowid or 0 without repeating the where clause

```
insert into comment
(select @text, @userid, @date)
where (select count(*) from comment where body=@text and userid=@userid) == 0
select last_insert_rowid()
```

Comment: Is there a unique constraint on the columns (body, userid)?

Comment: @forpas no. I want to prevent double posting in case the user hits submit 5 times on accident. But the same comment can be said multiple times if they're in different threads or a few hours apart (I removed that to shorten the example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your version of SQLite is 3.35.0+ you can use the [`RETURNING`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_returning.html) clause to get the `rowid` of the inserted row like this:

```
WITH cte(body, userid, date) AS (SELECT @text, @userid, @date)
INSERT INTO comment (body, userid, date)
SELECT c.* 
FROM cte c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM comment t WHERE (t.body, t.userid) = (c.body, c.userid))
RETURNING rowid;
```

The drawback is that in case of a failed insertion the query returns nothing.
If your app can check the number of returned rows you can translate that as 0.

See the [demo](https://www.mycompiler.io/view/1a4083T03YL).

Comment: Thats pretty neat. I had no idea sqlite supported cte. It's been a while since I touched a DB

Answer (score -1):

Do nothing. Your query already returns 0 if there was no update.

The [last_insert_rowid documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#last_insert_rowid) says

> The last_insert_rowid() SQL function is a wrapper around the sqlite3_last_insert_rowid() C/C++ interface function.

And the [documentation for sqlite3_last_insert_rowid](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/last_insert_rowid.html) says

> If no successful INSERTs ... have ever occurred ..., then sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(D) returns zero.

Comment: I reuse the same connection for multiple queries. Can I reset the id some how?

Comment: @cal maybe not, but you could try it in a new transaction.

Comment: @Bohemian The part you stripped out of your second quote makes it pretty clear that a transaction won't reset the last insert rowid to zero... "If no successful INSERTs into rowid tables have ever occurred on the database connection D, then sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(D) returns zero."

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo OP didn't say the connection had prior use, and I only said "you could try" a transaction. Opening a new connection for this purpose is not the worst solution. It is sqlite being used so the micro performance hit of opening a new connection is almost certainly not a problem.